# How to get a token to access one of my facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-authentication

So here's the deal, I'm learning how to work with facebook api, and I'm having some difficulties trying to understand it, the documentation isn't at all organized *imho*.

So I'm getting this error "Impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API"

And I think it's because I copied the token from the graph API explorer.

My main purpose with this project is to have a normal website, that fetches some data of my facebook page(albums, photos and events) and display it on the website as page content. It's like the facebook page is the backoffice.

How can I solve this?

Here's a real example, of what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://codecanyon.net/item/facebook-album-gallery/full_screen_preview/400462

Comment: Did you try to use an FQL query with a page access token (one from the /me/accounts result)?

Comment: I copied the token from the graph api explorer. I've been digging around, and even if I build a page just to authenticate my app I can't save that token so I can use it later, for that purpose I have the offline token, but the offline token expires after 60days(?). Basically what I want is a permanent way to access to a page wich I administrate so I can fetch the photo albums and events

Comment: I don't know why are you got this error, but i think your goal should be doable if your admin page authenticates it's user on facebook and the user is an admin on the page you want to admin. This way every time your user log in into your app have a way to fetch a long living access token and you are good for the next 60 days, hoping that the user will come back before token goes bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that FB documentation is to be nice..."unorganized".

Regardless there are a few steps required to get the access tokens.. copying from FB explorer wont work.

1. Register an FB app
2. Use the FB app ID and secret key to create a .php page (for example) to get a user to give you specifically requested permissions
3. When the user completes the request for permissions, FB will redirect the user to your specified callback and append an access_token to the URL
4. parse that token, and store it somewhere
5. use that access_token to get the data off the API that you want
6. If the access_token is permanent then you can use the stored token for later to get more data offline.

I modified the example code as follows to create the apps permissions grabbers:

```
$app_id = "myappid";
$app_secret = "mysecret";
$my_url = "http://mycallbackurl";
session_start();
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
(empty($code)) {
 $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
 $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $my_url 
   . "&scope=offline_access,manage_pages,read_stream,read_insights,export_stream,read_friendlists";

  }else{

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

  $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
  $params = null;
  parse_str($response, $params);

  $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
   . $params['access_token'];

 $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
 $at = $params['access_token'];
 $uid = $user->id;
 $un = $user->name;

 ...and so on
```

Comment: But with this method I will need to login with my facebook after 60 days to revalidate the token right?

Comment: not if you set scope=offline_access (see $dialog_url above), this sets the permissions to not expire until the user manually revokes permissions.

Comment: jsut wanted to add that the offline_access token is being replaced so if you don't use the currently authenticated token then yeah after 60 days you'll have to refresh it